# How can I create a Views list of all users with either a node OR a comment?

Tags: views

I need to do some major user pruning. I run a Q&A site and need to find all users who have written a comment or created a node . Currently in Views I can't figure out how to do this.

Is it possible in Views or do I need a custom query ? What might that query look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't create Views for more than one entity type. You would have to create separate Views, one for nodes and one for comments; you CAN however make them appear in the same page by using [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view). You can sort each view by author, and get rid of duplicates by using the Aggregation option.

**EDIT:**
There IS a way to do two EntityFieldQuery (one for node and one for comment) and then create a single array of authors. Something like this:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');
$node_list = $query->execute();

$query2 = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query2->entityCondition('entity_type', 'comment');
$comment_list = $query2->execute();

$author_ids = Array();

$nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($node_list['node']));
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $author_ids[] = $node->uid;
}

$comments = comment_load_multiple(array_keys($comment_list['comment']));
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
  $author_ids[] = $comment->uid;
}

$author_ids = array_unique($author_ids);
dpm($author_ids);
```

You can then do whatever you want with the list of uid's - for example load  the users and create a table programmatically for display.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will give it a try. Basically this is the use case and I was hoping to use Views so could use VBO to run the deletion.

Comment: The use case is that I have a 10+ year old Drupal Question and Answer site, http://yeahchemistry.com. There are users who have created nodes (questions) and never commented. There are users who have commented (answers) but never posted a node. I need to clean up the user table. So I'm looking for all users who have not posted a node or a comment and a way to delete them using Drupal hooks.